# image browser imageBrowser_listUrl not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plugins, ckeditor, getjson

i have tried to get the plugin Image-Browser to work, but i cant figure out, what im missing here.

im using this class:

```
public class GetImagesToJsonClass
        {

            public string image { get; set; }
            public string thumb { get; set; }
            public string folder { get; set; }
        }
```

and this JsonResult

```
 public JsonResult GetFiles()
    {

        List<GetImagesToJsonClass> GetFiles = new List<GetImagesToJsonClass>();

        DirectoryInfo GetDIR = new DirectoryInfo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/"));
        foreach (FileInfo item in GetDIR.GetFiles())
        {
            GetImagesToJsonClass NewFile = new GetImagesToJsonClass();

            NewFile.image = string.Format("/Content/Images/{0}", item.Name);
            NewFile.thumb = string.Format("/Content/Images/{0}", item.Name);
            NewFile.folder = "Test";
            GetFiles.Add(NewFile);

        }
        string GetJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetFiles);



        return Json(GetJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

using this on a "test" site

```
 <script>  
var myURL = '@Url.Action("GetFiles", "Sales")';

     var Getfiles = $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         url: myURL,
         data: "",
         datatype: "Json",
     });

     Getfiles.done(function () {
         try {

             var tempdata = (Getfiles.responseText);
             var data = JSON.parse(tempdata);

             document.write(data);
         }
         catch (e) {
             alert("fejl:" + e);
         }

     });</script>
```

and the output is:

```
[{"image":"/Content/Images/testimage2.jpg","thumb":"/Content/Images/testimage2.jpg","folder":"Test"}]
```

and ofc this to activat it

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
        "extraPlugins": 'imagebrowser',
        "imageBrowser_listUrl": "/Sales/Test"
    });
```

And get an error

```
parsererror: invalid JSON file: "/Sales/Test/": Unexpected token <
```

and if i set the feed directly in i get a [object, object] error?

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: If you're already using `return Json()`, there's no need to serialize the data yourself beforehand. Try `return Json(GetFiles, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. Also, in your JavaScript, there's no need to call `JSON.parse` as you already set the `dataType` to "json". Try: `Getfiles.done(function(data) { // data is your returned array });`. Also, you'll have to change `datatype` to `dataType`. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/